# Not able to access s3 from ec2 instance using "hadoop fs -ls s3a://bucketname" command

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, distcp

I have installed Hadoop in psuedo-distributed mode on one ec2 instance. I have hdfs and yarn running.
I have assigned s3fullaccess role to my ec2 instance and able to access s3 using "aws s3 ls" command from instance.
I have specified my access & secret key and s3 endpoint in core-site.xml file.
I want to do below 2 operations and I am getting similar kind of exceptions in both cases.

1. I want to access s3 using "Hadoop fs -ls s3://" syntax. But I am getting the below error while doing so.

   [ec2-user@ip-172-31-32-98 hadoop]$ hadoop fs -ls s3a://rprakashb1/
   -ls: Fatal internal error
   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 534FB9EFD4258AED, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID: UNgDNpEzqaqoAct1Qy/SL/O7VkCYWuFFjgXVqqNrwfW9IECNfFV2GOumb3izPEtdaf+8tlS7qHg=
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
2. I have tried distcp between hdfs and s3 using "hadoop distcp hdfs://path/to/file s3a://bucket/" and I am getting exception like below.

20/04/24 13:58:42 ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 97DC19225BA431D1, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID: GKWk8Q/0QX4NJDmiyJQeMnLwo32BlaXZX0Q/KTGmGk4BNzQwdEe/pXFVbe8WXv+bo1Brtzz6FIM=
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)

Please let me know how to fix this. Tried so many things and searched over internet for the fix, but I was not successful. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Have you given the appropriate S3 bucket policies for actions like GetObject,PutObject?

Comment: yes. please check -------> {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1587737294541",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1587737290866",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::596014996634:user/ram_dev"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ramprakashb3"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Can you give the principal as "*" and try?

Comment: I tried giving *, getting access denied error. Can you please be little specific. I tried like this "Principal" : { "AWS" : "*" }. Please let me know if I am wrong

Comment: This is correct what you have mentioned above. Mostly S3 exceptions are caused due to incorrect bucket policy , CORS configuration and inappropriate IAM role permissions given to other services for calling S3. Maybe can you check the accesskey and secret key given to instantiate S3Client and region . Check if that user/role with the  accesskey has appropriate permissions

Comment: Thank you. I haven't done anything on CORS configuration. Please let me know if I have to. I have tried with both using the root user and user who has admin access. Both instances and s3 buckets are in same region Mumbai.I gave s3FullAccess role to EC2 instance. I believe, I would not have been able to s3 using aws s3 ls command, if there is access ID key issue.

Comment: Cors is required only if you are accesing your buckets from browser. Not required in this case